# Customize a WordPress theme based on another one - alternatives to grandchild themes

Tags: wordpress, svn, themes

I have a client who has asked me to develop a WordPress theme based on an existing one. My first thought was to create a child theme, but - his clients will need to have custom themes based on the one he's asking me for.

I know "grandchild themes" are a bad practice - I don't like them, either. I can create a new parent theme based on the original theme, and then, he'll have child themes of this to be released to his clients.

In order to let the final users easily upgrade their child themes, would it be appropriate to make a branch of the existing theme using Subversion? I'm not very familiar with version control, so I'm not sure if this is the best choice. What I need is to have every theme up to date whenever the one it relies on releases a new version.

None of these themes will be listed at WordPress.org, I think.

Sorry for my bad English.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAICS, you want to implement [vendor branches](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.vendorbr.html). Using vendor branches allows you to keep your child themes synced with parents.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to copy the external theme (with svn copy) into the root directory of my theme, and not under a vendor subdirectory? Most of the files will remain unchanged. Otherwise I'd need to mirror each .php file with a single "include vendor/XXX.php". The images would be even more difficult to import this way.